# Can't remove padding underneath image ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm trying to add in an image into ion-content, essentially as a top banner, but there's some pesky padding that's automatically added below it that I just can't seem to remove. The code is:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
    <img src="http://impact.byu.edu/style/wide_banner6.gif" style="width:100%; padding:0px">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item item-divider"> 
        Settings
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This codepen demonstrates what I'm talking about https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkvObV. I want to remove the spacing between the bottom of the image and the "Settings" item-divider. Anyone know how? I've tried using padding/margin properties in css to no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `display: block;` to the `img` tag and see the Magic!

Explanation:

By default, an image is rendered inline, like text. All inline-block elements has some vertical-align value by default- reset it either by applying `vertical-align: top` or reset the display property by applying `display: block`

Comment: That worked. That was amazingly simple, would you mind explaining a bit about how you debugged the situation? I tried hunting around in console for hours but I couldn't find anything...

Comment: Added explanation to the answer :) could you please upvote / mark answer as accepted too? Thanks!

Comment: I can't accept an answer for another few minutes, but I will right after. I also wanted to ask about another minor css issue I had, if you look at the codepen again I updated it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkvObV and added a button right under the banner, that also has a small sliver of padding that I can't remove, any advice on how to remove that?

Comment: :) `padding-top: 1px;` on `.list` coming from `iconic.css`